# Git rebase onto a tag when master and a branch is ahead of the current commits

Tags: git, rebase

I am having difficulties with Git. I am following a remote repo on my local machine. The master branch is being updated from the remote and I always sync with it to get the updates. And then my local branch ("feature" branch) is rebased onto the master branch to apply my local changes. The issue is I forgot to rebase my local branch onto master branch's version tag. instead I rebased onto the latest commit of master branch. Now I want to rebase my local branch to master's version tag branch without losing my local changes. Any ideas how to do it?

```
                          o -- o
                         /     ^ feature branch
o --- o --- o --- o --- o --- o --- o 
      ^ V2.0                        ^ master (origin/master)
```

I want to rebase my "feauture" branch like this:

```
        o -- o
       /     ^ feature branch
o --- o --- o --- o --- o --- o --- o 
      ^ V2.0                        ^ master (origin/master)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Checkout the git rebase manpage https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.

The remote branch `origin/master` (assuming your remote is called origin) is the upstream master. Rebase works by selecting a common ancestor between two branches and then cut off one part:

```
                          o -- o
                         /     ^ feature branch
o --- o --- o --- o --- C --- o --- o 
      ^ V2.0                        ^ master (origin/master)
```

Note that `C` is the common ancestor between the `feature-branch` and `origin/master` This is what git rebase later will use when we use `git rebase origin/master feature-branch`.

Let's cut off the following:

```
                        [ X -- X ]
                         /     ^ feature branch
o --- o --- o --- o --- C --- o --- o 
      ^ V2.0                        ^ master (origin/master)
```

and attach it to v2.0. So let's do it:

```
git stash          #  move local uncomitted changes away
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase --onto v2.0 origin/master
git stash apply    # reapply uncommitted changes
```

### Rebase

The rebase command will calculate the common ancestor between `origin/master` and your current branch. It will then cut off all the commits that are unique to your branch. (think about it as asking rebase for everything on `feature-branch` that is not also on `origin/master`). Now that we know what we cut off, we use the the `--onto` to specify the target. In our case a tag.

Comment: I think I did not say correctly. master and origin/master are the same for me. I only applaying new features onto the master branch. So I do not do anything with master. Master is being updated by the remote. I apply my features to "feature" branch on my local.

Comment: worked like a chram. Thank you for your kind help. Appreciated.

Comment: @somnium Can you do the same thing also with a commit hash? Say, commit that was tagged with v2.0 has hash `123abcde`, then you could also type `git rebase --onto 123abcde origin/master` and it would have the same effect?

Comment: @somnium your second link is dead

Comment: @mrisek thank you for noticing it! I removed the link since the blog is no longer available.